# How do you revert the cartesian product of two columns in SQL in order to get the columns before computing the cross join (cartesian product)?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's assume I have two columns: letters and numbers in a table called tbl;

```
letters   numbers
a         1
b         2
c         3
d         4
```

Doing a cartesian product will lead to :

a                  1   
a                  2   
a                  3   
a                  4   
b                  1   
b                  2   
b                  3   
b                  4   
c                  1   
c                  2   
c                  3   
c                  4   
d                  1   
d                  2   
d                  3   
d                  4

Write a query that reverts the cartesian product of these two columns back to the original table.

I tried multiple methods from using ROWNUM to selecting distinct values and joining them (which leads me back to the cartesian product)

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT NUMBERS
      FROM TBL
      ORDER BY NUMBERS) AS NB
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT LETTERS
      FROM TBL
      ORDER BY LETTERS) AS LT1
```

which led me back to the cartesian product....

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Huh?  What is this supposed to mean?  First, this is not a Cartesian product.

Comment: I've updated the question, i hope it makes sense now.

Comment: The main problem in this question is that SQL tables/resultsets are defined in the ANSI/ISO SQL standard to be **orderless** because off that there is no way to construct the source data from a (precalculated) cartesian product table, The best you can get are the unique values from the `letters` and or `numbers` column there is no way to construct the pairs before the cartesian product table...

Comment: I agree with Raymond Nijland - Only knowing the cartesian product, there is no way to know, how the "original table" looks like. There are 4! (= 4*3*2*1 = 24) possible answers.

Answer (score 1):

This is a version that works with 5.7.

```
SELECT `numbers`,`letters` FROM
 (SELECT   `numbers`,
      @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
 FROM      Table1 t, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
 GROUP By `numbers`
 ORDER BY  `numbers`) NB1
INNER JOIN
 (SELECT  `letters`,
      @curRank1 := @curRank1 + 1 AS rank
 FROM (
  Select `letters` FROM Table1 t
  GROUP By `letters`) t2, (SELECT @curRank1 := 0) r
  ORDER BY  `letters`)  LT1 ON NB1.rank = LT1.rank;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cc17c2cfeff049edc73e437e5e4fd892

As Raymond and Ankit pointed out you have to know which order have the letters and even the order of the numbers has to be defined prior or else you never get a correct answer.

Another way of writing this:

```
SELECT numbers 
     , letters 
  FROM
     ( SELECT DISTINCT numbers
                     , @curRank := @curRank + 1 rank
                  FROM Table1 t
                     , (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
                 ORDER 
                    BY  numbers
      ) NB1
   JOIN
      ( SELECT letters
             , @curRank1 := @curRank1 + 1 rank
          FROM 
            ( SELECT DISTINCT letters 
                         FROM Table1 t
            ) t2
            , (SELECT @curRank1 := 0) r
        ORDER 
           BY  letters
      )  LT1 
     ON NB1.rank = LT1.rank;
```

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I was after. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you have a better alternative, I would be curious to see it.

Comment: no sorry as i pointed out, it is impossible for an algorithm to rank the items, because it makes no difference for it  if i join a with 1 or b with 1. So i introduced the ranking system, because it is simple and  you can copy the interior of each join and rank the real items however you want

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the order will never be destroyed and is deterministic, You can use dense_rank() analytic function to achieve it back -

```
SELECT LT1.LETTERS, NB.NUMBERS
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT NUMBERS
      FROM TBL
      ORDER BY NUMBERS) AS NB
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT LETTERS, RN
      FROM (SELECT LETTERS, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY LETTERS) RN
            FROM TBL
            ORDER BY LETTERS) T) AS LT1
ON NB.NUMBERS = LT1.RN
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=012da3a48c0fd03115e8397537c190dc)

Comment: The main problem in this question is that SQL tables/resultsets are defined in the ANSI/ISO SQL standard to be **orderless** because off that there is no way to construct the source data from a (precalculated) cartesian product table, these results are based on "luck" and assumptions  that the source table and the cartesian product table has a fixed order..

Comment: What is the JOIN good for? [This one](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a8e3ef24cac67b193ced9e1c42515c71) returns the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is oversimplifying the problem, but it should be seen that this, or some variation of it, would suffice...

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
+---------+---------+
| letters | numbers |
+---------+---------+
| a       |       1 |
| a       |       2 |
| a       |       3 |
| a       |       4 |
| b       |       1 |
| b       |       2 |
| b       |       3 |
| b       |       4 |
| c       |       1 |
| c       |       2 |
| c       |       3 |
| c       |       4 |
| d       |       1 |
| d       |       2 |
| d       |       3 |
| d       |       4 |
+---------+---------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT x.*
     , @i:=@i+1 numbers 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT DISTINCT letters 
                  FROM my_table
     ) x
     , (SELECT @i:=0) vars 
 ORDER 
    BY letters;
+---------+---------+
| letters | numbers |
+---------+---------+
| a       |       1 |
| b       |       2 |
| c       |       3 |
| d       |       4 |
+---------+---------+
```